# Material Strength on Mars

Tags: gravity, material-science

Apologies if this is on the wrong site, I was bouncing between here, Space Exploration and even considered Worldbuilding.

Currently NASA among others is looking at automated systems that could take material from the Martian surface, refine the useful materials from them and build basic structures out of them which in turn could be then used as habitats by colonists whenever they eventually arrive.

I appreciate this is very far away into the future but curiosity got the better of me, all foundry processes such as casting and molding work perfectly fine on Earth, but Mars' gravity is roughly 1/3rd of Earth's.

**Question: would the lower gravity during the entire refining process affect the strength of these materials?**

So this is to assume that the materials are mined/gathered, refined and constructed from a 1/3rd gravity (in this case Mars) environment. It is safe to assume that this would most likely occur inside some form of craft or structure on the surface so I think a human friendly atmosphere would be somewhat expected during this. So this question is just about the effect lower gravity would or wouldn't have on the materials, not the Martian atmosphere. I am thinking far more about the strength of these materials but welcome alternate effects if there are any.

Again, apologies if this is better elsewhere.

Comment: I think this might be better on a materials science SE, if there is one?  It's arguably a physics question I agree but I wonder if anyone here knows enough about the details of steel production, say, to be able to make any reasonable answer.  I'm sure that the answer in general is 'no'  for Mars (production in *microgravity* is different however) but I don't feel competent to write a good answer.

Comment: As a materials scientist, I'm having a really hard time coming up with something that might be a show stopper. Perhaps some of the flotation methods for ore separation would have to be tweaked? (As a side note, a non-human friendly atmosphere might be preferred in many cases which would be easy to arrange on Mars and is pretty hard here on Earth).

Comment: @JonCuster, Ha, well I'm happy with run of the mill if show stopper is not possible. That's interesting, i hadn't thought about the benefits of an inhospitable atmosphere on the production process.